# Uploading an image to FTP server on windows phone

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, ftp, webclient

Please Help! I've tried everything, i dont know what else to do. I just want to upload an image that the user chooses from their library to my websever.

I already have a code that uses webclient to upload to a url.

```
 private void OnChoosePicturel(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PhotoChooserTask task = new PhotoChooserTask();
            task.Completed += task_Completed;
            task.Show();
        }
        private void task_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
        {
            if (e.TaskResult != TaskResult.OK)
                return;



            const int BLOCK_SIZE = 4096;

            Uri uri = new Uri("URL");

            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            NetworkCredential g = new NetworkCredential();
            g.UserName = "USERNAME";
            g.Password = "PASSWORD";
            wc.Credentials = g;
            wc.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;
            wc.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

            try
            {
                // what to do when write stream is open
                wc.OpenWriteCompleted += (s, args) =>
                {
                    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(e.ChosenPhoto))
                    {
                        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(args.Result))
                        {
                            long bCount = 0;
                            long fileSize = e.ChosenPhoto.Length;
                            byte[] bytes = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
                            do
                            {
                                bytes = br.ReadBytes(BLOCK_SIZE);
                                bCount += bytes.Length;
                                bw.Write(bytes);
                            } while (bCount < fileSize);
                        }
                    }
                };

            }
            catch(Exception t)
            {


            }

            // what to do when writing is complete
            wc.WriteStreamClosed += (s, args) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Send Complete");
            };

            // Write to the WebClient
            wc.OpenWriteAsync(uri, "STOR");
        }
```

The problem is , the `webclient` class only works for `"http"` urls, but i need to connect and upload the file to an `"ftp"` url. How do i do this?  Ive tried EVERYTHING. Nothing works.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what exception you are getting. Also, you may use StreamSocket to connect to ftp server.

Comment: @Ritesh Khichadia but the ftp server requires authentication.  how do I authenticate myself using streamsocket? how would the server know how to read the file and what to name it?